# jQuery Validate plugin: callback when element value is valid

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            if(element.hasClass('chosen-select')){
                error.insertAfter(element.next());
                element.next().addClass('error');
            }
}
```

When no value is selected in select element using the above code I can easily add class error to my desired element. But the problem is when element's value is valid (In this case when any option is selected) How to remove that class I added in errorPlacement event?

Is there any event that is fired when element value is valid?

Comment: Have you checked the docs?  Every callback function is listed [here](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    if(element.hasClass('chosen-select')){
        error.insertAfter(element.next());
        element.next().addClass('error');
    }
}
```

The `errorPlacement` callback function is only fired *once* to place the initial error label.  It will not work as error messages come and go, because the plugin automatically toggles those.

The `success` callback is fired on a valid element.  However, that is used to toggle the error label.  Example, when you want to place a message or an object like a green check-mark next to a valid element.  You mention toggling classes, so it seems you might not want `success`.

I can't say for sure which will work out for you because you have not provided a concise working demo.  However, it looks like you should be using the `highlight` and `unhighlight` callback functions if you want to toggle classes.  Keep in mind that, by using your own custom `highlight/unhighlight` functions, they will replace the plugin's defaults.

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    if(element.hasClass('chosen-select')){
        error.insertAfter(element.next());
    }
},
highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).next().addClass('error');
},
unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).next().removeClass('error');
}
```

And since the default error class is `error`, you can simply use the `errorClass` argument.

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    if(element.hasClass('chosen-select')){
        error.insertAfter(element.next());
    }
},
highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).next().addClass(errorClass);
},
unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).next().removeClass(errorClass);
}
```

[See the docs for all available callback functions and options](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/).

---

**Additional Reference**

These are the default callback functions:

```
highlight: function( element, errorClass, validClass ) {
    if ( $(element).attr("type") === "radio" ) {
        this.findByName($(element).attr("name")).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
    } else {
        $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
    }
},
unhighlight: function( element, errorClass, validClass ) {
    if ( $(element).attr("type") === "radio" ) {
        this.findByName($(element).attr("name")).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
    } else {
        $(element).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
    }
}
```

Source:  http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js

Comment: @coure2011, I only followed the plugin's source code.  However, you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `success` callback function, it *is* possible to get a reference to the actual form element that failed validation is possible. The example below adds a class to the parent div of each form field when they fail validation, and then removes the error class once the field passes:

```
form.validate({
        rules: {
            Name: {
                required: true
            },
            Email: {
                required: true
                , regex: "^[0-9a-zA-Z.+_\-]+@{1}[0-9a-zA-Z.+_\-]+\\.+[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$"
            }
        },
        messages: {
            Name: {
                required: "Please give us your name"
            },
            Email: {
                regex: "Please enter a valid email address"
            }
        },

        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            element.parent().addClass("error");
        },

        success: function(element) {
            $("#" + element.attr("for")).parent().removeClass("error");
        }
    });
```